# Switching between two nested while loops within one while loop

Tags: java, loops

I am a rookie programmer having issues with an assignment of mine that contains while loops.

Currently, I'm programming the combat system of a game that has two phases that need to loop between each other (an attack and a defence phase). It's created as a method that I will be able to call upon more than once through the game. How I had intended the code to work was by creating a while loop that would continue until one of the actor's hit points reach 0. Next, I nested while loops within the first while loop to use booleans that would meet conditions of the nested loops to continue switching between the two. However, after testing the code and trying other methods of looping the code, it appears to get stuck looping the defence phase and not switching back to the attack phase.

I would really appreciate feedback and help to prevent the code from doing that. Ignore the "Use Item" bit of code too, I have yet to add that in as a choice so it's merely text for now.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CombatSystemTesting 
{
// Combat Variables
public static boolean attackStance = true;
public static boolean defenceStance = false;

// Player Variables
public static int playerGold = 0;
public static int playerHP = 20;
public static int playerArmour = 0;
public static int playerShield = 1;
public static int playerAttack = 3;

// Enemy Variables
public static int enemyHP = 12;
public static int enemyDF = 0;
public static int enemyAttack = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    battle1();
}

    public static void battle1()
    {
        int enemyAttackChance = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
        int enemyDefendChance = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (playerHP <= 0 || enemyHP <= 0);
        {
            while (attackStance = true)
            {
                System.out.println("(Attack Phase)");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("'1' - [Attack]");
                System.out.println("'2' - [Strike]");
                System.out.println("'3' - [Use Item]");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("HP: " + playerHP + " DF: " + playerArmour + " Gold: " + playerGold);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Enemy HP: " + enemyHP + " Enemy DF: " + enemyDF);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Your choice: ");
                int choice = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("");

                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    if (enemyDefendChance == 1 || enemyDefendChance == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Attack!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Defend!");

                        enemyDF = enemyDF + 1;
                        playerAttack = playerAttack - enemyDF;
                        enemyHP = enemyHP - playerAttack;
                        playerAttack = playerAttack + enemyDF;
                        enemyDF = enemyDF - 1;

                        attackStance = false;
                        defenceStance = true;
                    }
                    else if (enemyDefendChance == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Attack!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Counter!");
                        System.out.println("");

                        playerAttack = playerAttack - enemyDF;
                        enemyHP = enemyHP - playerAttack;
                        playerAttack = playerAttack + enemyDF;

                        attackStance = false;
                        defenceStance = true;
                    }
                }
                if (choice == 2)
                {
                    if (enemyDefendChance == 1 || enemyDefendChance == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Strike!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Defend!");
                        System.out.println("");

                        playerAttack = playerAttack * 2;
                        enemyDF = enemyDF + 1;
                        enemyHP = enemyHP - playerAttack + enemyDF;
                        enemyDF = enemyDF - 1;
                        playerAttack = playerAttack / 2;

                        attackStance = false;
                        defenceStance = true;
                    }
                    else if (enemyDefendChance == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Strike!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Counter!");
                        System.out.println("");

                        playerHP = playerHP - playerAttack * 2 + playerArmour;

                        attackStance = false;
                        defenceStance = true;
                    }
                }
            while (defenceStance = true)
                {
                System.out.println("(Defence Phase)");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("'1' - [Defend]");
                System.out.println("'2' - [Counter]");
                System.out.println("'3' - [Use Item]");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("HP: " + playerHP + " DF: " + playerArmour + " Gold: " + playerGold);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Enemy HP: " + enemyHP + " Enemy DF: " + enemyDF);
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.print("Your choice: ");
                choice = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("");

                if (choice == 1)
                {
                    if (enemyAttackChance == 1 || enemyAttackChance == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Defend!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Attack!");

                        playerArmour = playerArmour + playerShield;
                        enemyAttack = enemyAttack - playerArmour;
                        playerHP = playerHP - enemyAttack;
                        enemyAttack = enemyAttack + playerArmour;
                        playerArmour = playerArmour - playerShield;
                        System.out.println("");

                        attackStance = true;
                        defenceStance = false;
                    }
                    else if (enemyAttackChance == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Defend!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Strike!");

                        enemyAttack = enemyAttack * 2;
                        playerArmour = playerArmour + playerShield;
                        playerHP = playerHP - enemyAttack + playerArmour;
                        playerArmour = playerArmour - playerShield;
                        enemyAttack = enemyAttack / 2;
                        System.out.println("");

                        attackStance = true;
                        defenceStance = false;
                    }
                }
                else if (choice == 2)
                {
                    if (enemyAttackChance == 1 || enemyAttackChance == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Counter!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Attack!");

                        enemyAttack = enemyAttack - playerArmour;
                        playerHP = playerHP - enemyAttack;
                        enemyAttack = enemyAttack + playerArmour;

                        attackStance = true;
                        defenceStance = false;
                    }
                    else if (enemyAttackChance == 3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You used: Attack!");
                        System.out.println("Rat Used: Counter!");
                        System.out.println("");

                        playerAttack = playerAttack - enemyDF;
                        enemyHP = enemyHP - playerAttack;
                        playerAttack = playerAttack + enemyDF;

                        attackStance = true;
                        defenceStance = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       
    //Pending code will be added later
    System.out.println("You shouldn't see this message till you or oppenent have reached 0 HP");
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Java is [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) language and you have no class. Is this a restriction of your assignment ?

Comment: Isn't the "public class CombatSystemTesting " near the top of my code the class? Pardon me if I'm incorrect, I have only started coding since about a year or so ago, I'm not 100% familiar with all the terms involving java.

Comment: True but if you actually had 0 class, you couldn't execute anything. I meant I see no import and you didn't use any object except `Scanner`.

Comment: I think what @MickaëlB is trying to say, is that you have everything in one class, instead of breaking everything into smaller, focused classes. (Like Player and Enemy should both be their own object)

Comment: Also, Enemy*Chance is assigned once at the start of battle... so is the enemy suppose to reuse the same move for the entire battle?

Comment: @MickaëlB - I suppose that I haven't completely familiarized myself with classes enough then to create separate bits of code like that. I lack the knowledge to use them other than what I have created here.

Comment: @Tezra - I did find that issue out soon after posting this and had fixed the placement of the random number generator. However, thank you still for pointing out that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defenceStance = true` is an assignment, not a compare, so `while(defenceStance = true)` will always be true, because it is testing that the assignment was successful. You need to use `==` instead to compare values. But since you are testing true, you can just say `while(defenceStance)` since bool == true will always result in just the value of bool.

Comment: Thank you! A subtle thing I didn't notice! I appreciate the help and it appears to work as I had originally intended now.